# LoopBack accessToken in invoked method observer

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I have two LoopBack models, A and B. Part of their code is like this:

```js
A.beforeRemote('create', function (ctx, unused, next) {
  ...
  B.findById(idForB, callBack);
  ...
});

B.observe('access', function (ctx, next) {
  const token = ctx.options && ctx.options.accessToken;
  const userId = token && token.userId;
  ctx.query = ctx.query ? ctx.query : {};
  ctx.query.where = ctx.query.where ? ctx.query.where : {};
  ctx.query.where.allowedUserId = userId;
});
```

Now, B's access observe hook has accessToken when REST calls are directly made from B/ API.

However, when making an API POST A/ API call, A's beforeRemote hook on create attempts to call B.findById which in turn triggers B's access observe hook, but in this scenario, there is no accessToken; not even option.

How do I propagate access information from A to B?

Answer (score 1):

You pass it along in the options argument. As mentioned below, if you're doing something custom make sure the options.accessToken is set or set it yourself. findById etc already have the mechanism to provide the options-object.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html

> Any additional context is passed in the “options” argument. Built-in
>   methods such as PersistedModel.find or PersistedModel.create already
>   accept this argument, custom user methods must be modified to accept
>   it too.
>
> Whenever a method invokes another method, the “options” argument must
>   be passed down the invocation chain.
>
> To seed the “options” argument when a method is invoked via a REST
>   call, the “options” argument must be annotated in remoting metadata
>   with a specific value set in the “http” property.
>
> Optionally, applications can customize the value provided to “options”
>   when invoked via REST.

Comment: >Whenever a method invokes another method, the “options” argument must be passed down the invocation chain.

In `A.beforeRemote('create',` hook, I am invoking `B.findById`. I am not sure how to _pass down the options_.

Comment: Make it a promise like they do in the example and pass it along as the third argument.